# iPhone: Xcode 4.1 doesn't show up Distribution build configuration

Tags: iphone

I developed an iPhone application and want to use Distribution scheme to build and upload to App store. I recently updated Xcode 4.1. When i search for Distribution setting build configuration, it doesn't show up. It shows only Release and Debug.

Could someone help me to get this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check it out Build configuration for [Distribution](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html)